# Xanthan Gum Use in Tamarind Chutney

Tags: indian-cuisine, condiments, chutney

How much xanthan gum should be used to thicken a large 24 quart pot of hot tamrind chutney to get a smooth pourable tamrind chutney when we cool?  Currently use 2 lbs of corn starch but it spoils the taste of the chutney.

Answer (score 2):

24 quarts would be about 23 kilos. Xantham gum is generally used for thickening in an amount of .15% to .5% by weight. So the expected range would be 34 to 115 grams. Start small, thickening with xantham gum can get snotty. Work up slowly, mixing thoroughly, until you reach the thickening you want. You may find that a combination of cornstarch and xanthan gum is ideal.

Comment: At the higher end of that range, I've had things get unpleasantly slimey. Often, a mixture of Xanthan, Guar and Locust bean gums is used to avoid the downside of using any of them to excess.